# How to change Linear layout's items visibility in a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-linearlayout

I have a linear layout in a Listview and need to change some items' visibility within the linear layout when the Linear Layout gets selected. Due to the design, the Listview has no idea what the linear layout is and thus can't explicitly refer to any item in this layout. In this case, what will be the best solution to trigger the visibility change in the Linear layout?

```
 listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(
                    final AdapterView<?> adapterView,
                    final View view,
                    final int position,
                    final long id) {
                        //the View is a linearlayout
                        //will need to trigger its items visibility 
                    }
                }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one possible solution is to call a method on the selected view, that will do what you want. Considering that you are using a custom view, it will look like this:

```
list.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        MyCustomView entry = (MyCustomView) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

        // Now you call some method that changes the visibility of whatever you want
        entry.doSomeStuff();
    }
});
```

Ps: in this example I used a custom view, but of course it can be your LinearLayout, if that's what you only have, although it would be more appropriate to use a custom class, for better encapsulation.

Comment: yeah, the tricky part is I can't cast the entry to MyCustomView here since it's hidden from the caller.

Comment: @GreenHo Hidden how? You mean, the class isn't accesible from this point? Are you trying to change the behavior of some 3rd party library?

Comment: Right, by hidden i mean the listview doesn't know/care about the custom view due to encapsulation. the custom view exists in another package.

Comment: Ok, but just to make sure: such package is not accessible due to protection level, or something like that? If so, you can use some reflection, because every view will be a `android.view.View` class. So if you really don't have access to the class, jus reverse engineer its internal strucutre, and retrieve the desired reference using reflection

Comment: The CustomView class is intentionally not accessible here for encapsulation purpose, so the caller doesn't care what the CustomView wants to do but just wants to trigger the update and let the CustomView take care of the logics internally